# How to make sure git shows every conflicts?

Tags: git

I was planning to merge remote branch B into my local branch A. I want to make sure no code is erased during the merge process. That means show all the conflicts to me, I will then decide to keep ours or others. I don't want git to silently either keep ours or keep other. Is there any special argument that I need to pass to git merge? or It is by default doing that.

Comment: First of all, you have to understand differences in the *strategies*, such as **ours** and **theirs**. Manual for Git merge is pretty much descriptive.

Comment: I thought ours keep mine and theirs keep theirs. But I don't want that. Because some time I might want both.

Comment: What do you mean by *wanting both*? Any example? (Edit the question by adding simple example what you have and what you want in such cases)

Answer (score 0):

Chose the safest way.

1. Create copy of your local branch A:

> git checkout -b copyBranchAName

2. Merge remote branch B into you copyBranchAName
3. Resolve all conflict i it'll be and if you will be satisfied, repeat that on your branch A or merge copyBranchAName into A branch.